# Why my Java socket proxy hangs transferring data?

Tags: java, groovy, proxy

I've written a simplest abstract "socket proxy" that just reads from incoming connection and transfers all the data to another server and back. There is no any analysis of data transferred.

I start my proxy, then `git remote show origin`. Then 517 bytes are transferred to "bitbucket.org" throu the proxy and then **everything hangs** - no more bytes from `git` and no answer from "bitbucket.org". (Bitbucket and SSL are just for purposes of investigations.)

How to make data to flow?

Full code in Java/Groovy:

```
void main() {
    ServerSocket reader = new ServerSocket(443)
    Socket clientSocket = reader.accept()

    Socket remote = new Socket("bitbucket.org", 443)

    Thread t1 = Util.createThread("request-transfer") {
        Util.copy(clientSocket.inputStream, remote.outputStream)
    }

    Thread t2 = Util.createThread("response-transfer") {
        Util.copy(remote.inputStream, clientSocket.outputStream)
    }

    t1.join(); t2.join();
}

static void copy(InputStream src, OutputStream dest) {
    log.debug("transferring bytes from IN to OUT")
    while (true) {
        byte[] buf = new byte[10*1024]
        int copied = src.read(buf) // I know about -1
        log.debug("read $copied bytes")
        dest.write(buf, 0, copied)
        dest.flush() // added later
        log.debug("copied $copied bytes")
    }
}
```

Output:

```
transferring bytes from IN to OUT
transferring bytes from IN to OUT
read 517 bytes
copied 517 bytes
< it hangs here >
```

Comment: did you try to flush the stream?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Just added `dest.flush()` after `dest.write()`. Didn't help.

Comment: Tested locally with a browser, "it works" - well, it allows only one connection, and the process never stops (because the threads never exit). If git needs multiple connections, then it can fail with such behavior